# How to Get ImageView (not Node) from GridPane

Tags: javafx, row, gridpane

I have to get an ImageView from a GridPane.

I use this code, but it is for Node, while I'm trying to change an Image in an ImageView (inside GridPane).

```
private Node getNodeFromGridPane(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
      for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
         if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row) {
            System.out.println(node);
            return node;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
```

Is there a solution?

I already searched to lots of posts, but there is not this problem solved.
Thank you

Comment: You know that [an ImageView *is* a Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html), right?  Just check if the node is an instance of ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On caller side you may do the next:

```
final Node foundNode = getNodeFromGridPane(gridPane, col, row);
if (foundNode instanceof ImageView) {
    //do something
}
```

`instanceof` will care for both ImageView and null.